# Kotlin: Fetching data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm struggling to find an efficient way to fetch individual values from my Firebase Database. I'm coming from working with Swift. When using Swift to fetch data from Firebase, it was as simple as creating a dictionary and accessing the data through that and that allowed me to have access to that one value to do something with it. E.g

```
guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
let username = dictionary["username"] as? String

if username == "Bob" {
  // do something
}
```

I can only find documents and answers online that use for loops to loop through the snapshot in Kotlin. Is there a much for efficient way to do this? Here's all I can find online. Here's a snippet to get you started. I really appreciate it.

```
mReference.getReference("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
        val children = snapshot!!.children
        println("count: " + snapshot.children.count().toString())
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can simplify loop. Like this

```
//by using Iterable function

snapshot.children.filter {
                    children -> children.hasChild(targetUserKey)
                }.map {
                    children -> children.key
                }.first()
```